# Const correctness, std move and smart pointers

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I'm struggling to understand when should I use const smart pointers and when to move them.

Based on the following code:

```
class Foo;
class Bar;

typedef std::shared_ptr<Foo> FooPtr;
typedef std::shared_ptr<Bar> BarPtr;

class Bar {

};

class Foo {
public:
    static FooPtr create()
    {
        FooPtr f = std::make_shared<Foo>();
        f->initialize();
        return f;
    }

    void setData(const BarPtr& b) {
        m_b = b;
    }
private:
    BarPtr m_b;
};

inline const FooPtr& internalCreateFoo(const BarPtr& b)
{
    FooPtr foo = Foo::create();
    foo->setData(b);

    int id = foo->getID();
    m_foos[id] = std::move(foo);

    return m_foos[id];
}
```

1: is `std::move(foo)` really necessary here?

2: what happens regarding the `std::move` if `foo` is created as a `const`, like `const FooPtr& foo = ...`?

Comment: Why do you want to move a _pointer_? It's like moving an int. And why do you use shared_ptrs? Note that a factory method returning a shared ptr is generally a bad idea. It should better remove a unique_ptr, so the receiver is free to change the ownership.

Comment: What's the point of `std::static_pointer_cast`? `Foo::create()` already returns the matching type.

Comment: "move" const object generally ends with copy.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that's actually a cast of types held by the smart_ptrs, but I simplified the code and forgot to take that off.

Comment: @ypnos As far as I know, an `int` is a primitive and a `smart_ptr` is a whole data structure.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino I was confused by your static pointer cast. But in any case, there is not much point in moving a shared_ptr either. Or returning a reference to a shared_ptr. It just makes your interface more confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is `std::move(foo)` really necessary here?

Necessary, no, useful, yes.  Without the `std::move` `foo` is an lvalue so it will cause a copy.  That can be inefficent.  Since you don't need `foo` any longer, it makes sense to move it into the array instead of copying it.

> what happens regarding the `std::move` if `foo` is created as a `const`, like `const FooPtr& foo = ...`?

Then you would get a copy.  You can't move something that is `const` since moving  alters the state<sup>1</sup> of the moved from object.

<sup>1: In theory a move might not need to alter the state of the moved from object, but then your just making a copy anyways.</sup>

Comment: If I used `return std::move(foo)` in some scenario, would the move be implicit already?

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino Baring a couple exceptions, `return std::move(foo)` is not needed.  the return statement will treat local variables and function parameters as rvalues to try and move them (be more efficient).